# ElasticSearch to query only fields of type string in the meta object or any specified object

Tags: javascript, typescript, elasticsearch

I am writing an elastic search query where I need to search data with all the keys in meta object, since the elastic-search only search on string types, I would like to know if there is a way to filter only fields of type string  in meta objectto be searched?

Please see my query and results example.

Query example:

```
GET /people/_search
{
"query": {
  "bool":{
    "must":{
      "query_string":{
        "query":"severe*",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": false,
        "fields": ["meta.*"]
      }
    }
  }
},
"size":10
}
```

Results:

```
{
       "_index" : "people",
       "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "fd0eebef-62a8-4c46-a199-685327655",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "fd0eebef-62a8-4c46-a199-35267523556",
          "createdAt" : "2022-04-26T07:23:30.899Z",
          "lastUpdate" : "2022-04-26T07:27:28.123Z",
          "meta" : {
            "status" : "finished",
            "corrosion" : true,
            "detectionStatus" : "severe"
          },
          "owner" : "john.doe",
          "perms" : {
            "*" : {
              "allowed_users" : [
                "OWNER"
              ]
            }
          }
}
```

Comment: you mean, query should not search in `corrosion` field which is type of `boolean` ?

Comment: @SagarPatel yes, query should not search in corrosion field